# I cannot access sql server from the client app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql

i have  a C# windows app trying to access database based the connection string stored in teh app.config file

Here is my app.config parameters

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="con1" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1\THOR;database=KINGSROAD;uid=glen;pwd=123456;integrated security=True" /> 

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

the reason i want to put an ip address on connection string i just want to create connection strings as people do in their work. When the app tried access the connection string it was given the following error.

[image]

because i haven't used this user/password for a long time I'm pretty sure the user name and password is correct but i have the following questions

1. Assume the user and password is incorrect, is there way to reset this?
2. what other configuration that i need to do in order to make the C# app access this Database?

i use SQL server 2008R2 developer edition

thaks

Comment: There's no place like 127.0.0.1 :)

Comment: You have integrated security and a uid/pwd combo. Choose one or the other.

Comment: there is some hinted questions: 1.do you exactly read and use connection parameters from the above config file? 2.have you configured your SQL Server correctly to be connected from client? 3.have you entered the IP address or server name in the config file correct? 4.review again the connection string in the config file, 5.etc

Comment: @FarhangAmary the values in the connection string are for demo purposes and they are not real except for the IP address. Answer to the second question is i cant remember becuase so far have used the connection for a local connection and it was a simple connection string and answer to the 3rd question is in the real connection string IP and Server name is accurate

Comment: @Jeremy 127.0.0.1 refers to local network adapter on the computer and if there is then 127.0.0.1 points to localhost or local or . or current cumputer

Comment: @Farhang I'm aware of that. The IP Address is also called "home" so I was making a joke, hence the smily face.

Comment: @Jeremy i want use IP address format for the server, this is what typically used in my case i have only one PC so i used the locahost address

Comment: check to see if you can log in using those credentials using sql management studio. If you are using the free version, I think there is a free SSMS avilable, or you can use Visual Studio to connect to the database.

Comment: @Jeremy unfortunately i could NOT. As i assumed becuase i havent used those credential for a long time so is there way to reset these credentials?

Comment: no idea short of a reinstall. There may be something on google.

Comment: however, if you're the machine admin you should be able to get without a username, but through windows authentication. If you can get in that way, you can reset the password of anyone.

Comment: @Jeremy assume i have reisntalled the SQL server, Is there anything else i need to configure before client access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to reset the password, you have to log on the SQL Server Management studio and 
   go to security -> Logins
   right click on the user and set the new password
2. One item could be the open SQL Server Configuration Manager and check if required client protocols are allowed (TCP/IP)